# Error in my POD when importing GoogleMLKit/TextRecognition

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Im getting the following error when trying to add MLKit. I even tried to use the Firebase one and that failed as well, similar error.

This is what I am trying to follow.

https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/text-recognition/ios

This is what is in my pod file.

```
  pod 'MaterialComponents/ActivityIndicator'
  pod 'MaterialComponents/Chips'
  pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK'
  pod 'IQKeyboardManagerSwift'
  pod 'Alamofire'
  pod 'SwiftyJSON'
  pod "SearchTextField"
  pod 'Firebase/Core'
  pod 'Firebase/Auth'
  pod 'Firebase/Storage'
  pod 'Firebase/Database'
  pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
  pod 'Toast-Swift', '~> 5.0.1'
  pod 'GoogleMLKit/TextRecognition','2.2.0'
```

Finally, here is the error I am getting.

```
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "GTMSessionFetcher/Core":
  In snapshot (Podfile.lock):
    GTMSessionFetcher/Core (< 4.0, = 3.1.0, >= 2.1)

  In Podfile:
    GoogleMLKit/TextRecognition (= 2.2.0) was resolved to 2.2.0, which depends on
      MLKitTextRecognition (~> 1.3.0) was resolved to 1.3.0, which depends on
        MLKitVision (~> 1.3) was resolved to 1.3.0, which depends on
          GTMSessionFetcher/Core (~> 1.1)

Specs satisfying the `GTMSessionFetcher/Core (< 4.0, = 3.1.0, >= 2.1), GTMSessionFetcher/Core (~> 1.1)` dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.
```

What do I do to fix this issue, as I really need to get MLKit added to the project.

UPDATE:

I found this : https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/254418199

This also did not work for me.

```
Fetching podspec for `MLKitCommon` from `MLKitCommon.podspec.json`
Fetching podspec for `MLKitVision` from `MLKitVision.podspec.json`
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "GTMSessionFetcher/Core":
  In snapshot (Podfile.lock):
    GTMSessionFetcher/Core (< 4.0, = 3.1.0, >= 2.1)

  In Podfile:
    MLKitVision (from `MLKitVision.podspec.json`) was resolved to 4.2.0, which depends on
      GTMSessionFetcher/Core (~> 2.1)

Specs satisfying the `GTMSessionFetcher/Core (< 4.0, = 3.1.0, >= 2.1), GTMSessionFetcher/Core (~> 2.1)` dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.
```

Comment: Try to remove version `,'2.2.0'` from  `'GoogleMLKit/TextRecognition'`

Comment: i did that too.